# How to tell if my laptop will support a second monitor

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I have a Toshiba Satellite P775(given by employer) and google isn't really giving me an answer about multiple monitors. Is there a way to tell if my laptop will support a second external monitor(3 screens total) on its HDMI port?

I need so I don't purchase a HDMI cable and a HDMI->DVI adapter.

Comment: You can get simple HDMI->DVI cables, as they are electrically compatible for video.  No need for a (separate) adapter.

Comment: What does the spec say on Toshiba site for the model? I doubt you'll be able to do 3 screens.

Comment: Is the only way to check the specifications of the computer, as opposed to a menu in the bios or OS, like other hardware info?